# How to compare if two dates are closer to each other

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, sorting

I want to check if two dates are within a range of each other, and reorder my array. I need to compare the dates from an array with the current date.

I have this:

```
var currentDate = new Date(); /* current date = 2021/08/18 */
listOfObjects = [ { "user": "John", "date": "2021-08-20" }, { "user": "Bob", "date": "2021-08-17" }, { "user": "Joe", "date": "2021-08-09" } ]
```

The **return** shoud be like this:

```
[ { "user": "Bob", "date": "2021-08-17" }, { "user": "John", "date": "2021-08-20" }, { "user": "Joe", "date": "2021-08-09" } ]
```

Comment: And the actual problem is? Convert the date strings into actual dates and compare them in a custom `.sort()` callback -> What have you tried so far to solve this on your own ([How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users))?

Comment: **The wording is confusing.** Are you maybe trying to sort an array in a way that the result starts with the entry that has the least distance from today and ends with the entry that has the greatest distance? What about same-distance entries? Is the sorting stable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, an array is sorted by sorting the textual representation of its items.

> The default sort order is ascending, built upon converting the elements into strings, then comparing their sequences of UTF-16 code units values.  
> <sub>(Source: [Array.prototype.sort() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort))</sub>

See following example:

```js
const numbers = [1, 30, 4, 21, 100000];
numbers.sort();
console.log(numbers);
```

We see that the output is the array with alphabetically sorted numbers:

```
1, 100000, 21, 30, 4
```

In most cases, this is not what we want (or what most people expect). To sort numbers numerically, we pass a custom compare function to sort:

```js
function i_cmp(a, b) {
    let d = a-b;
    if (d < 0)
        return -1;
    if (d > 0)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

numbers.sort(i_cmp);
console.log(numbers);
```

**output:**

```
1,4,21,30,100000
```

To sort an array by a criterion that depends on further conditions, it's handy to pass a function bound to runtime values that is created by another function. Here we sort items by their absolute distance of a fixed value `x`.

```js
function d_cmp(x) {
    return function(a, b) {
        let d = Math.abs(a-x)-Math.abs(b-x);
        if (d < 0)
            return -1;
        if (d > 0)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}

numbers.sort(d_cmp(50));
console.log(numbers);
```

**output:**

```
30,21,4,1,100000
```

[Hemera already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68832522/2932052) how to get date distances. The rest, accessing `date` attributes, should be easy to implement.

---

For a live demo of above code (combined) see: https://ideone.com/e7DaOx

Comment: @John does this mean your goal is sorting the array by absolute distance between today and the items' date attribute? Maybe the question should be updated then to clarify your intent. (that's BTW what the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68832489/edit) function is for)

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract the dates and compare the results. Like `new Date("2021-08-18") - new Date("2021-08-17") = 86400000` cause dates are saved as milliseconds from a random but standardize reference date.
Then you can use this difference by using `Math.abs(number)` as a condition for finding the nearest dates to the given one and put it in a simple sorting function like below:

```js
function orderByDateDistance(nDate, nList){
    // easy sorting by finding the current min (also working with max)
    for(let tA=0;tA<nList.length-1;tA++){ // iterating over all except the last will be sorted
        let tIndex = tA; // current index
        let tDifference = Math.abs(nDate-new Date(nList[tA]["date"])); // current difference
        for(let tB=tA+1;tB<nList.length;tB++){ // iterating over unsorted list part
            if(Math.abs(nDate-new Date(nList[tB]["date"])) < tDifference){ // compare current difference with stored
                tIndex = tB; // save index
                tDifference = Math.abs(nDate-new Date(nList[tB]["date"])); // save value optional
            }
        }
        // change items
        let tBuffer = nList[tA]; // save current object
        nList[tA] = nList[tIndex]; // copy next lowest object
        nList[tIndex] = tBuffer; // copy buffered object
    }
    return nList; // optional returning
}

// Your example
console.log(
    orderByDateDistance(
        new Date("2021/08/18"),
        [
            {"user": "John", "date": "2021-08-20"},
            {"user": "Bob", "date": "2021-08-17"},
            {"user": "Joe", "date": "2021-08-09"}
        ]
    )
);
```

Comment: That's not a solution, it's a suggestion. It will not, by itself, produce the required output in the OP.

Comment: @Hemera I think that your approach is correct, but you could elaborate this. The question itself is confusing, so maybe clarifying what you guessed it is (obviously) about would help others to understand what's going on.

Comment: @RobG Then it's your turn to find the dublicate entries for sorting and iterating lists, handling Javascript Objects and finally dates in Javascript :D cause of course this question can be solved by more resarch but this was the main misssing core: Not knowing how to compare dates.

Comment: Given the dates are in ISO 8601 format, they can be compared lexically without conversion to Date. ;-)